# Keep edited text in custom cell when adding another section ([tableView refresh data])

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have a nib file with a custom UITableViewCell and view controller with a TableView that contains three of the custom cells per section. I also have a button that when pressed, adds a new section with another three custom cells.

My problem is, I have a placeholderArray = @"Name", @"Position", @"Email"; that is used to set the text for each of the cells. And advisorArray to contain the user input of the three textFields. The user input saves into this array but when the user presses the button to add another set of cells, the original three cells text are changed back to the textFieldArray instead of the user text. 
I know the [tableView refreshData] is what is causing this but I do not know another way to add another section to the tableView.

```
- (NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
return 3;
}

- (NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
return sections;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath{
CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCell"];
cell.tag = indexPath.row;

[cell.textField setText:[self.placeholderText objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

cell.textField.delegate = self;
cell.textField.tag = indexPath.row;

return cell;
}


- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

if (textField.tag == 0) {
    self.nameString = textField.text;
    [self.advisorsArray replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:self.nameString];
}
if (textField.tag == 1) {
    self.positionString = textField.text;
    [self.advisorsArray replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:self.positionString];
}
if (textField.tag == 2) {
    self.emailString = textField.text;
    [self.advisorsArray replaceObjectAtIndex:2 withObject:self.emailString];
}

}

- (IBAction)addAdvisor:(id)sender {
sections++;
[self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is `self.placeholderArray` in

```
[cell.textField setText:[self.placeholderText objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

Where is the actual data stored.  Do you mean to use `self.advisorsArray` ?

Comment: sorry I wasn't clear. placeholderArray is the array that contains the @"Name", @"Position", @"email". And the advisorsArray is the array that contains the data from the cell.textField

Comment: The placeholderText array only contains the placeholder text for the textFields..."Name", ".", "." It doesn't change. The advisorArray is the array that will contain the user input.

Comment: The problem isn't with saving the data, the data saves to the array. But when i tap the addAdvisor button to add another set of textFields in a new section, the original textFields text changes back to the placeholder text instead of the text staying as what the user typed in

Comment: As far as i understand the table reloads and you using the data from self.placeholderText in the cellForRowAtIndexPath which will set the txt back to the original text

Comment: yea thats where I'm stuck. I don't know how to set the new cells with self.placeholderText and keep the old cells as they are

Comment: You only need one array to hold the data.  As far as i understand you are letting the user to edit text in the cell and when they are done to set that text in the cells.  You only need the advisorsArray and start with placeholder text and then replace it when user enters the info.

Comment: Try and change the self.placehoholderText with self.advisorsArray in the cellForRowAtIndexPath and see what happens when you try to enter data.